# String format Check gives unexpected result (Regex)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to check format of a string which is `ABC-nnn`, where `ABC` represents alphabets (English) in capital letters. `nnn` represents triple digit number for example `123` or `001` or `012` A complete example would be `FBI-026`. I used `regex` for that and below is my code.

```
public bool IsSubstringMatchingFormat(int numberOfLettersBeforeHyphen, int numberOfNumbersAfterHyphen, string stringToMatch)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex($@"^[A-Z]{numberOfLettersBeforeHyphen}-\d{numberOfNumbersAfterHyphen}");
    return regex.IsMatch(stringToMatch);
}
```

I call it `IsSubstringMatchingFormat(3, 3, "SMB-123")` but it returns `false`. Please provide your insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you actually checked what the string you are passing into the regex looks like? ie evaluate `$@"^[A-Z]{numberOfLettersBeforeHyphen}-\d{numberOfNumbersAfterHyphen}"`and see if that is the regex you want? I can tell you that it isn't because it will end up being `^[A-Z]3-\d3` which does not do what you want.

What I think you'll want is:

```
$@"^[A-Z]{{{numberOfLettersBeforeHyphen}}}-\d{{{numberOfNumbersAfterHyphen}}}"
```

This adds the escaped curly braces back into your regex to give:

```
^[A-Z]{3}-\d{3}
```

The equivalent of this using `String.Format` would be:

```
String.Format(
    @"^[A-Z]{{{0}}}-\d{{{1}}}",
    numberOfLettersBeforeHyphen, 
    numberOfLettersAfterHyphen);
```

Comment: nice. I'm stuck with .net 2, hence my answer below :D

Comment: Thank you. I understand my mistake now.

Comment: @Kell: The op clearly isn't though... And I'd personally replace the interpolation with `String.Format` if I was trying to make it workable on earlier versions.

Comment: String interpolation is beautiful. String.format, not so much. Probably why we now have string interpolation.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar: Hopefully you also learnt a lesson in debugging too. :)

Comment: @Kell: I personally find the `String.Format` solution I've now added to be much nicer than the `String.Replace` of your solution.

Comment: Yeah, it's a personal choice. That makes my eyes bleed.

Comment: I'd probably use shorter names to make it more readable in my code. Another personal choice/style

Comment: @Chris Debugging is the thing I learned. I was just in a hurry. Want to go home for Christmas.

Comment: @Kell, shorter names are fine but a variable name must clear. I refrain from using some short names which does not make sense.

Comment: @Kell: That's fair. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your curly braces are being consumed by the string interpolation and are not making it into the regex. If you try to print the regex, you'll see it's something like

`^[A-Z]3-\d3`

Which is something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The {} are being removed when you format. Try this:

```
        public static bool IsSubstringMatchingFormat(int numberOfLettersBeforeHyphen, int numberOfNumbersAfterHyphen, string stringToMatch)
    {
        var expre = @"^[A-Z]{numberOfLettersBeforeHyphen}-\d{numberOfNumbersAfterHyphen}";//
        expre = expre.Replace("numberOfLettersBeforeHyphen", numberOfLettersBeforeHyphen.ToString())
            .Replace("numberOfNumbersAfterHyphen", numberOfNumbersAfterHyphen.ToString());
        Regex regex = new Regex(expre);
        return regex.IsMatch(stringToMatch);
    }
```